# Why I can't use my classes from Models folder in Global.asax.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to do following project for learning purposes:
https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create_the_data_access_layer

But I got stuck on the step "Updating the Global.asax file" - VS doesn't allow me to import WingtipToys.Models namespace to Global.asax.cs file.

[Here's the project structure, Globa.asax.cs and 'using' error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIADR.png)

Everything is done according to Microsoft's tutorial above.
Why can't I to import my models to global.asax.cs file?

My ProductDatabaseInitializer class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WingtipToys.Models
{
    public class ProductDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ProductContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ProductContext context)
        {
            GetCategories().ForEach(c => context.Categories.Add(c));
            GetProducts().ForEach(p => context.Products.Add(p));
        }....
```

Comment: please post your `ProductDatabaseInitializer` class

Comment: Sure, added it to my question.

Comment: can you try cleaning and rebuilding the solution as well as closing and opening visual studio...I don't see any reason for your code not to work.. have you saved the `ProductDatabaseInitializer` class after creating it and defining the namespace?

Comment: Yep, I did reopen VS and saved everything. Still have the same problem: 
http://prntscr.com/nalw2z

Comment: Try changing your namespace from `WingtipToys.Models` to just `Models`. My guess is that your default namespace (look at the Project properties) is `WingtipToys`, so your model is really in `WingtipToys.WingtipToys.Models`. Also, try downloading a 30-day Resharper demo. It's really good at fixing that stuff for you. As a result I hardly ever have to spend any time messing with namespaces.

Comment: I tried to change namespace to Models, didn't work as well. But here's the thing.
I deleted all classes and created them again. Now it works perfectly.
The only difference is as on screen: http://prntscr.com/naotji 

Now I have 'triangles' near each class so I can open it and see its properties etc. Does anybody know what difference it makes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did really help is a re-creation of all classes in Models directory (delete all old classes and create new ones with same code) - then I started to see my classes from Global.asax.cs file.

Maybe it could help someone.